# Do elements in `std::array<int, N>` as a class member get default intialised

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, stdarray, std-variant

Consider:

```
class x {
    std::array<int, 4> data_;

public:
    x() /*no reference to data_ here*/ {}
};
```

Do the `int` elements in `data_` get zeroed, or is their value indeterminate?

By extension is that also true in this case:

```
class x {
    std::variant<std::array<int, 4> /*other stuff here*/> data_;

public:
    x() /*no reference to data here*/ {
        data_.emplace<std::array<int, 4>>(/* no args */);
    }
};
```

**EDIT:**

Extension: Is there a way I can get the desired behaviour from the variant (to *not* initialise the data).

If I pair the two example together I should be able to do:

```
struct no_init_array {
     std::array<int, 4> array;
     no_init_array() { } //does nothing
};

class x {
    std::variant<no_init_array/*other stuff here*/> data_;

public:
    x() /*no reference to data here*/ {
        //call default ctor of no_init_array
        //which does not init the std::array (I hope)
        data_.emplace<no_init_array>(/* no args */);
    }
};
```

Comment: That depends on when and where and how you define objects of the `x` class. Global? Local? Static? Function argument? Part of another object?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude local function variable is the case I am "concerned" about. The variant case the the one I am most interested in - for the clarity I *want* the data to be uninitialized.

Comment: Then the data should be uninitialized. It's really no different from having e.g. a plain `int` member variable, it too will be uninitialized.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude correct me if I am wrong, and I *hope I am*, but isn't there a difference between `struct x { int i; };` and `struct x { int i{}; }`, and isn't emplace effectively doing the latter? Again, I hope I am wrong here.

Comment: There *is* a difference, but that's not what you're doing in the first `x` class shown in the question. If you had e.g. `std::array<int, 4> data_{};` it would be a different thing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that seems to be at odds with what others are saying. It seems to me that calling emplace will effectively do: `std::array<int, 4> data_{};` rather than `std::array<int, 4> data_;` if called with no args. Correct me if I am wrong though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`std::array` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), in the constructor's section, we can read:

> initializes the array following the rules of [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) (**note that default initialization may result in indeterminate values for non-class T**)

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

In your case, you have a `std::array<int, 4>`. `int` matches the definition of a non-class type so the default initialization will let the `data_` member contents with indeterminate values.

If you had initialized the `data_` member as:

```
std::array<int, 4> data_ {}; // Note the braces
```

The elements would have been value-initialized which would lead to zero-initialization for `int` elements.

---

**Edit** (from comments):

[`std::variant::emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/emplace) forwards its arguments but since you did not have provided any argument for the emplaced `std::array<int, 4>`, your `std::variant` will hold a value-initialized `std::array<int, 4>` so the underlying `int` elements will be zero-initialized.

---

Since you want the second use-case and you want the array contents to remain uninitialized, you can of course do what you suggested:

```
struct X
{
    std::array<int, 4> data_;

    X()
    {}
};
struct Y
{
    std::variant<X, /*...*/> data_ {};

    Y()
    {
        data_.emplace<X>();
    }
};
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/L4KRg2)

But you need to take care that the array contents will not be accidentally accessed before it is later on properly initialized.

**Edit:**

To initialize the `std::array` afterwards, you should make sure that it is performed through a reference and not a copy of the array (in order to avoid undefined behaviour by copying uninitialized data).

For example:

```
Y y;

//X x = std::get<X>(y); // Wrong
X & x = std::get<X>(y); // Right

x.data_[0] = 42;
x.data_[1] = 422;
x.data_[2] = 442;
x.data_[3] = 4422;
```

Comment: Thanks, but is that also true for the variant case? Does `variant::emplace` not forward its args onto the element constructor, and thus it is constructed with `{/*Args... expands to nothing*/ }` and therefore would be defaultly initialised? To be clear, I WANT the data to be uninitialised.

Comment: @111111 `std::variant::emplace()` does forward its arguments. But you did not provided any argument so I'm not sure to understand you're question. In your example, the emplaced `std::array` in the `std::variant` will follow the above quote for default initialization.

Comment: *"`std::variant` will hold a default-initialized `std::array`"* It should be value-initialized. Since you pass 0 arguments, the array is constructed using `std::array<int,4>(/*0 args here*/)`, which value-initializes it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for the response, is there a work around for what I want, would wrapping the std::array in a struct which inits a default ctor that does nothing achieve that I am after?

Comment: @111111 Yes, your first example will do what you want, the array contents will be indeterminate values [as you can see here](https://godbolt.org/z/fZLRxo).

Comment: @Fareanor the first part of the question basically trying to figure out where the behaviour diverges from the latter. It is actually variant that my usecase calls for, and I do *not want* the array to be initialised. Please see my edit - I am wondering if stitching the two examples together gets me the behaviour I need.

Comment: @111111 Yes, it works, but keep in mind that it's undefined behaviour to access uninitialized values. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Fareanor yeah I know, i am passing the buffer to another function which will initialise them for me in a tight loop on the "critical path". I don't want to initialise them twice unnecessarily.

Comment: @111111 It should be fine then. I would just mention that you will need to initialize them through a reference and not a copy of the variant (Do not do `X x = std::get<X>(y); x.data_[0] = 42;` but do `std::get<X>(y).data_[0] = 42;` instead) to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: @111111 You're welcome. I've edited my answer accordingly.